# List of 10 rectangles, meant to draw every one, only draws one

Tags: python, pygame

So I have a program that's supposed to append 10 instances of a class named Rectangle which creates random properties for the rectangle.
If I print multiple objects from the list, they appear as different values, but if I call the draw function I have for multiple, only one appears on the screen.

Here is the entire code: http://pastebin.com/hb6LBjss

The important bits of code here are these, the first is the rectangle class, the second appends a rectangle to an empty list 10 times, the third is in the main program loop and is supposed to draw all 10.

Thanks.

1.

```
class Rectangle():
    x = random.randrange(0, 701)
    y = random.randrange(0, 501)
    width = random.randrange(20,71)
    height = random.randrange(20,71)
    change_x = random.randrange(-3,4)
    change_y = random.randrange(-3,4)
    def move(self):
        self.x += self.change_x
        self.y += self.change_y
    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, green, [self.x,self.y, self.width, self.height], 0)
```

2.

```
myList = []

for i in range(10):
    myList.append(Rectangle())
```

3.

```
for i in myList:
    i.draw()
```

I've tried a whole bunch of different things such as this but every time there's just one rectangle on the screen.

```
for i in range(10):
    x = myList[i]
    x.draw()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in fact drawing 10 rectangles, but they are all the same one.

You have not passed instances of your rectangle class to be drawn, but the class itself.

It is an easy fix.

```
class Rectangle():
    x = random.randrange(0, 701)
    y = random.randrange(0, 501)
    width = random.randrange(20,71)
    height = random.randrange(20,71)
    change_x = random.randrange(-3,4)
    change_y = random.randrange(-3,4)
    def move(self):
        self.x += self.change_x
        self.y += self.change_y
    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, green, [self.x,self.y, self.width, self.height], 0)
```

Becomes:

```
class Rectangle():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = random.randrange(0, 701)
        self.y = random.randrange(0, 501)
        self.width = random.randrange(20,71)
        self.height = random.randrange(20,71)
        self.change_x = random.randrange(-3,4)
        self.change_y = random.randrange(-3,4)

    def move(self):
        self.x += self.change_x
        self.y += self.change_y

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, green, [self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height], 0)
```

---

The `init` method is called when you construct an instance of an object, by default, this does nothing. Since you wrote all those variables/members into the base class, as opposed to an initializer, then every instance of the class had the same values for all variables/members, since they became class members, not instance members...

Comment: Thanks!
I knew it was going to be something simple like that.

Comment: @JackWright Sorry, but everything is working on my end, are you sure you copied it correctly? Are you using the `draw()` method, or have you done something else? the `Rectangle()` class does not have `x` anymore, you need to make Rectangles by doing `a = Rectangle()` and then you can do `a.draw()` and `a.x`